# How can i show a list in a jsp file

Tags: jsp, servlets

This may seem like a simple question but I am 100% confused.

All I want to do is to be able to display a list of objects generated via a servlet into a JSP file.

Here is my servlet

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProductLoader p1 = new ProductLoader();
    List<Product> products = p1.getProducts();
    System.out.print(products);
    request.setAttribute("products", products);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/product.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

the result of     `System.out.print(products);` is `[Product [name=CHECK PRINT SHIRT, imgUrl=https://guesseu.scene7.com/is/image/GuessEU/M63H24W7JF0-L302-ALTGHOST?wid=1500&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&op_sharpen=0&op_usm=1.0,1.0,5,0&iccEmbed=0, price=110.0], Product [name=GLORIA HIGH LOGO SNEAKER, imgUrl=https://guesseu.scene7.com/is/image/GuessEU/FLGLO4FAL12-BEIBR?wid=700&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_sharpen=0&amp;op_usm=1.0,1.0,5,0&amp;iccEmbed=0, price=91.0], Product [name=CATE RIGID BAG, imgUrl=https://guesseu.scene7.com/is/image/GuessEU/HWVG6216060-TAN?wid=700&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_sharpen=0&amp;op_usm=1.0,1.0,5,0&amp;iccEmbed=0, price=94.5], Product [name=GUESS CONNECT WATCH, imgUrl=http://guesseu.scene7.com/is/image/GuessEU/WC0001FMSWC-G5?wid=520&fmt=jpeg&qlt=80&op_sharpen=0&op_usm=1.0,1.0,5,0&iccEmbed=0, price=438.9], Product [name='70s RETRO GLAM KEFIAH, imgUrl=https://guesseu.scene7.com/is/image/GuessEU/AW6308VIS03-SAP?wid=700&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_sharpen=0&amp;op_usm=1.0,1.0,5,0&amp;iccEmbed=0, price=20.0]`

But how do I show this as a JSP?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626755/java-servlet-request-getparameter-and-request-setattribute-connected-in-a-way-i answers your question?

Comment: no because it is not about showing a list of objects on a jsp